# ¿Cómo hacer que al escribir una palabra me diga en qué línea está?

Tags: c++

Tengo este código, pero en vez de decirme en qué línea está la palabra ingresada, éste cuenta palabra por palabra.

**¿Cómo hacer que al escribir una palabra me diga en qué línea está?**

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream> 
#include<sstream> 
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int n = 0;
  std::string c;
  std::ifstream examen("examen.txt");
  std::string temp;
  if (examen.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "escriba la cadena a buscar?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> c;
  }

  while (examen >> temp) {
    if (temp == c)
      std::cout << n << std::endl;
    ++n;
  }
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Parece que eso es lo que hace el código que compartes, ¿no?

Comment: no, mi programa cuenta palabra por palabra.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar `std::getline( )`, cuya misión es esa: leer líneas.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream> 

int main() {
  int n = 0;
  std::string c;
  std::ifstream examen("test2.cpp");
  std::string temp;

  if (examen.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "escriba la cadena a buscar?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> c;

    while( std::getline( examen, temp ) ) {
      if( temp.find( c ) != std::string::npos )
        std::cout << n << std::endl;

      ++n;
    }
  }

  return (0);
}
```

Veras que he metido el `while( )` **dentro** del bloque `if( )`, para que no busque si el archivo no se ha podido abrir.

Comment: wow, esta muy bien lo que has echo, aunque el programa que pones muestra una linea menos, osea que si la palabra esta en la linea 3 el resultado es 2

Comment: @hugobarron jejeje fíjate bien. Es tu código, con cambios mínimos. Lo que pasa es que inicializas `n = 0`. Cámbialo por `n = 1`.

Comment: @hugobarron Otra cosa, mas en serio. **No** buscas palabras, sino **ocurrencias** de texto. Tenlo en cuenta. Si necesitas buscar **palabras**, con espacios antes y detrás, deja un comentario.

Comment: tienes razon, muchas gracias por la ayuda lo tomare en cuenta gracias otravez